# Rails 5 , waiting/loading screen until Model is ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, spinner

I searched and seen there are some answers but most are very old or seem inadequate.

Here is my flow:
(1) User submit a form.
(2) Controller sends a DelayedJob.
(3) At the end of the job the Model attribute status is "Done".

What I want is to show the user a loading/waiting screen until the status is "Done".

At the moment I did this in a very ugly fashion , using plain JS and reloading the page , checking the status and displaying the waiting animation while the status isn't "Done".

But this cause multiple accesses to the DB , router , and the user sees the page jumping when it's reloading.

I was thinking of using respond_to JS but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a plain javascript(jquery) and send an ajax get request to check a status of a job. Create special an action/controler for this(as example jobs#status or job_statuses#show). Reload page or just update content after the job will be completed.

You can too use web sockets to don't send  multiple requests.

Comment: "check_job_statuses#show" - nope! Better "job_statuses#show" :)

Comment: That's what I thought , once implemented I'll post how I did it and mark the answer as accepted. Thanks. (I hoped there was some more 'Rails way' to do it , oh well)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're fully right. Just want to propose a service controller, it should use `create` method - "check_job_statuses#create"

Comment: Solution posted , answer tagged and any improvements to my code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Kojin
@Sergio Tulentsev

It's a little ugly but it works (hopefully I didn't screw up anything while copying and changing the names to a something more generic).

***config/routes.rb:***

```
  get   'loading_screen/:id'     , to: 'model_name#loading_screen' , as: 'loading_screen'
  match 'loading_status'         , to: 'model_name#loading_status' , as: 'loading_status' , :via => [:get,:post]
```

***In model_name controller:***

```
def loading_screen
    @model_name = ModelName.find_by(id: params.try(:fetch,:id,nil))
    @id         = @model_name.try(:id)
end


def loading_status
    @model_name = ModelName.find_by(id: params.try(:fetch,:id,nil) 
    @id         = @model_name.try(:id)       
    @json       = { status: @model_name.try(:status) , id: @id }.to_json
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js do
        render layout: false
      end
    end
end
```

***Views loading_screen.html.erb:***

```
<script>
  function checkStatus( id ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/loading_status',
      data: { id: id } ,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res) {
        var status = res.status;
        var id     = res.id;
        console.log("json = " + JSON.stringify(res,null,2) );
        if ( status == "Done" ) {
          window.location = "/path_to_view_completed_results/" + id;
          myStopFunction();
        } else if ( count > 30 ) {
          myStopFunction();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  var id    = <%= @id %> ;
  var count = 0;
  var myInterval = setInterval(function(){ checkStatus( id ) }, 1000);
  function myStopFunction() { clearInterval(myInterval); }
</script>
```

***In loading_status.js.erb:***

```
<%= @json.html_safe %>
```